# Using pickle for in-memory "transaction"?

Tags: python, transactions, pickle, undo

A user can perform an action, which may trigger dependent actions (which themselves may have dependent actions) and I want to be able to cancel the whole thing if the user cancels a dependent action.

The typical way I've seen this done is some variant of an undo stack and each action will need to know how to undo itself, and then if a child action is cancelled the undo's cascade their way up.  Sometimes writing undo methods are tricky and there isn't always enough information in context to properly know how to undo an action in an isolated manner.

I just thought of a (potentially) easier way which is to just `pickle` the state of the (relevant parts of) program, and then the cancel would just restore to it's former state, without needing to create separate undo logic for each action.

Has anyone tried this?  Any gotchas to watch out for?  Any reason not to do this?

Edit: The dependent actions must happen after the parent action (and even whether there are dependent actions may depend on the result of the parent action), so just checking all the dependencies before doing anything isn't an option.  I guess you could say an action triggers other actions, but if one of the triggered actions cannot be performed, then none of it happened.

Comment: Well, this only works if the whole design is coupled loosely enough and if you don't miss anything you should save/restore. And even then, it could be wasteful. Sounds like a lot of hassle imho.

Comment: are the actions happening real time?  could you build up a context containing a list of actions to be performed but not do any of them until all the dependencies have fired (i.e. not been canceled) - this is kind of like a database transaction(in my mind)

Comment: @delnan You are correct that it does make the assumption that the design (at least what is to be pickled) is loosely coupled so that the state to be saved is completely isolated, and I've taken special care to do so (not specifically for this reason, just because it's good to do). I can see the argument for it being wasteful in memory, but I don't see how it's more of a hassle then writing undo code for tens (right now, will likely end up being in the hundreds eventually) of actions.

Comment: I guess it's also somewhat unique in that there's a lot of logic and state manipulation, but not very much data. (it's for a game, and yes I'm aware of game dev stack exchange, but I figured there's nothing in the question that's specifically game related.)

Comment: @Gabriel I should've mentioned it in the question, but the dependencies require that the parent action happens first, and whether or not there even is a dependent action depends on the result of the parent action.  For example's sake, say there's a rule that when you draw a card, if it's a heart, draw another one, but if you draw a spade, undo the whole thing as if it never happened.  You don't know the dependencies until after drawing the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you mentioned the data design is loosely coupled, so you I don't think you need to pickle it if it's in memory. Just take a copy of all the relevant variables, and the `transaction.abort()` would just copy them back, and `transaction.commit()` would then just remove the copy of the data.

There are issues, but none that you don't have with the pickle solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?  Is this the module you're referring to: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/transaction ?  The documentation seems sparse but it sounds like it would do what I want.

Comment: @Davy8: No, that's what I assumed you would call your transaction module/class. :-) Nothing wrong with the transaction module above, but it just contains a framework for transactions, you would have to implement the transaction mechanism yourself, so it doesn't help you.

Comment: Ah I see, so you're just saying make a deepcopy instead of a pickle string or something, and then wrap that in a transaction class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pickle to store your state if all elements of state are serializable (usually they are). The only reasons for not doing so:

- if you have to store pointers to any objects that are not saved in state, you will have problems with these    pointers after performing undo    operation.
- this method could be expensive,       depending on the size of your state.

Also you can use zip() to lower memory usage in exchange of raising CPU usage.